# How do I convert a string to a key value json / array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I get this string:

```
    arguments: {[

    { style: "fill: red; stroke-width: 1; stroke: black;" }
]}
```

I want to get the value of a specific attribute. I can already end up with the value of the style.

```
"fill: red; stroke-width: 1; stroke: black;"
```

I'm thinking to convert this to an array or a json so I can just search for the key. But I'm not really sure how to do it.

Comment: are you passing the style attribute or you are getting from some source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One line solution

```
var s="fill: red; stroke-width: 1; stroke: black;";
var dict = {}
s.split(";").map(function (e){ if (e) {var parts = e.split(":"); dict[parts[0].trim()] = parts[1].trim()  }})
//dict = {fill: "red", stroke-width: "1", stroke: "black"}
```

Answer (score 2):

Split the string into styles based on `;`, then split those based on `:`:

```
var ss = "fill: red; stroke-width: 1; stroke: black;";
var styles = {};

var parts = ss.split(/\s*;\s*/);

for ( var i = 0; i < parts.length; ++i )
  {
    var vv = parts[i].split(/\s*:\s*/);

    if (vv.length == 2)
      styles[vv[0]] = vv[1];
  }
```

After which, `styles` will contain:

```
{
  'fill': 'red',
  'stroke': 'black',
  'stroke-width': '1'
}
```

And can be accessed as:

```
console.log(styles['fill']); // etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could actually create an element and make this its style attribute, then check a particular style -- but as long as the string is consistently well-formatted using `split` will work.

```
var styles = arguments[0].style.split(";");
styles.forEach(function (style) {
    var pair = style.split(":");
    if (pair[0] == "fill") {
        pair[1] == "red";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To simply search for the value with a key, you don't need to convert it into an object. Here's an example:

```
var str = "fill: red; stroke-width: 1; stroke: black;",
    key = "fill";

str.match(new RegExp(key+": "+"([^;]+);"))[1];   //"red"
```